# TSP-PD with time constraints between pickups and deliveries

Tags: vehicle-routing, traveling-salesman

Has anyone ever encountered the following variation of TSP?  You have a TSP with pickups and deliveries, and in addition, for each pickup-delivery pair $(i,j)$, you have a constraint that the time you arrive at $j$, $t_j$, has to be at least a specified time after the time you arrived at $t_i$, i.e. $t_j \geq t_i + \alpha_i$.  The interpretation here would be that you're picking up eggs, but you can't deliver them until they've hatched.  :)

Comment: Does not ring a bell. However, the Dial-a-ride problem (DARP) typically has the opposite constraint (the time between pickup and delivery should not exceed some upper bound). Not sure how adaptable it is to your case though.

Comment: A web search for "tsp with time constraints" gives rise to some relevant scientific articles, for example [An Exact Algorithm for the Time-Constrained Traveling Salesman Problem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/170895) and [An Exact Algorithm for the Time-Constrained Traveling Salesman Problem](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6277176).